# Decomposing Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, toeplitz-matrices

I have a system that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{b}$.

$\mathbf{A}^{mn}\in\mathbb{R}$ is toeplitz matrix, and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are unknown. I am looking for a decomposition for $\mathbf{A}$ so that I can write $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$ where $\mathbf{B},\mathbf{C}$ are have a special structure that helps in finding $\mathbf{x}$

$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c & 0 \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\\ 
0 & a & b & \ddots & & \vdots \\\
0 & 0 & a & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & a & b & c\end{bmatrix} 
$$

I searched over net and found work related to this but I couldn't figure out where should I start from. Any lead will be much. Reference to any good book that specifically addresses this problem will be much appreciated

Comment: can you try iterative method? I knew there is a book on this topic (but I never read it) http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718850

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am excited to see something that will put things in an organized way. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix has a special structure, the degree of freedom of the matrix is just 3 no matter how big $n$ is ( assuming $A_{n\times n}$). Just three numbers , $a,b,$ and $c$ define the entire matrix, so it is likely that you may find a closed form solution that involves those variables, and indeed there is.

Since you have a tridiagonal matrix that is also a toeplitz, there is a simple closed form solution, the eigenvalues of a [Tridiagonal Toeplitz](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf) is given by, 
$$\lambda_k = a + \sqrt{bc}\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n+1}}, k = 1,2,\cdots n$$

The eigenvalues are allocated symmetrically with respect to $a$.

Once you know eigenvalues you can do an eigenvalue decomposition, which is a direct approach rather using iterative solver. Such matrices are also called banded Toeplitz matrices (see. [Banded symmetric Toeplitz](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/research/papers/TRENCH_TN_12.PDF)).